# How to get the length of a _bstr_t

Tags: c++, windows, string

I am copying a wstring to a _bstr_t using:

```
_bstr_t name;           
SysFreeString(name);   // Free previous string, if any.
name = SysAllocString(Member[k].Membername);
```

Now before I use "name" I want to check if it contains at least 5 characters. In other words, I want to check the length of it.

I didn't find a "countof" or "len" or something like that. Has anyone a idea?

Thanks,
Lumpi

Comment: What platform is this? Windows?

Comment: Your code contains a major bug: don't mix `BSTR` calls such as `SysFreeString` with `_bstr_t`. `SysFreeString` is used with `BSTR`, in C code; in C++ `_bstr_t` will manage memory for you. In particular, `_bstr_t::operator=` will call `SysFreeString` on the old string for you, so the bug in your code effectively contains a double-deletion bug. similarly, `_bstr_t::operator=` will call `SysAllocString` for the new string and copy your input, so _your_  `SysAllocString` leaks. I.e. your bug is also a memory leak.

Comment: Just noticed your comment... So I should skip the SysFreeString(name) and also simply assign name=Member[k].Membername without using SysAllocString.? This because _bstr_t does all that stuff for me. Have I understood you correct? Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
name.length()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx